# Python-Mysql : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database

I've installed `pymysql` package using all possible ways. 
Using :

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pymysql
sudo pip3 install pymysql
conda install PyMySQL
```

I checked the packages installed in my system using command :

```
sudo apt list --installed
```

I found following lines in result :

```
python3-pymysql/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,now 0.7.2-1ubuntu1 all [installed]
python-pymysql/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,now 0.7.2-1ubuntu1 all [installed]
And i can clearly see that pymysql is installed.
```

But when i import pymysql in any python program. It give me error

```
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql' ".
```

I don't know what i'm doing wrong. Please help.

Comment: How are you launching you python program?

Comment: I've used both terminal and jupyter notebook.  It's same error both ways .

Comment: It seems to be a environment problem. Are you launching `python3` and not `python`, right? Are you using `conda` or inside a `virtual environment` when you launch it?

Comment: i'm using conda. And yes i'm using python3 command.